# Azure template deployment for IoT Hub and diagnostics settings does not work

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub, azure-diagnostics, azure-rm-template

I'm using Azure RM Template deployments with a Visual Studio 2017 Resource Group project to deploy IoTHub instance with diagnostics settings in Log Analytics.

Deploying IoTHub alone is successful, the problem is with deployment of the Diagnostics Settings template.

I'm following the instructions for deploying Diagnostics Settings as [Non-Compute resource template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template#non-compute-resource-template)

The strange error that I receive is the following:

> Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
>   failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Insights/BasicDiagnostics'
>   for type 'providers/diagnosticSettings' at line '69' and column '9'
>   has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have
>   identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource
>   type must have segment length one greater than its resource name.

Why does it fail like this, even though I follow the documentation with the provided example?

Here are my template definitions:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku.name')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('sku.units')]"
      },
      "name": "[parameters('iothubname')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "eventHubEndpoints": {
          "events": {
            "retentionTimeInDays": "[parameters('endpoints.events.retention')]",
            "partitionCount": "[parameters('endpoints.events.partitions')]"
          },
          "operationsMonitoringEvents": {
            "retentionTimeInDays": "[parameters('endpoints.operationsMonitoringEvents.retention')]",
            "partitionCount": "[parameters('endpoints.operationsMonitoringEvents.partitions')]"
          }
        },
        "features": "[parameters('features')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.settingName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IoTHubs', parameters('iothubname'))]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.settingName')]",
        "workspaceId": "[parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.workspaceId')]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "Connections",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "Configurations",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "D2CTwinOperations",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          },
          {
            "category": "C2DTwinOperations",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "category": "AllMetrics",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs to be a sub resource of the IOT hub, not a separate resource.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs",
    "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku.name')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('sku.units')]"
    },
    "name": "[parameters('iothubname')]",
    "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        xxx
    },
    "features": "[parameters('features')]",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "providers/diagnosticsSettings",
            xxx
        }
    ]
}
```

},

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. So that's what they tried to explain with *"In the resources array of the resource for which you want to enable Diagnostic Logs, add a resource of type [resource namespace]/providers/diagnosticSettings."* "[resource namespace]" mislead me that the diagnostics resource should be in the array where the IoT Hub is defined. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the deployment completes successfully now, but ... this one  *"metrics": [ { "category": "AllMetrics", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": { ... } } ]* is not deployed as enabled - in the portal this is not checked as enabled. Tried multiple times, both as a new deployment and as an update. Do you have a hint on this? If I go and manually enable it in the portal it stays enabled after consequent deployment.

Comment: can you start a new question about this

Comment: This appears to no longer work.
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 420685af-7810-4b41-90a0-e5c775d88baa. {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceNamespace",
    "message": "The resource namespace 'providers' is invalid."
  }
}